# Exchange 2010 error opening EMC

Tags: exchange

I keep getting error when trying to open EMC.

The attempt to connect to ***.****.local\PowerShell using Kerberos authentication failed. The WS-management service cannot process the request. The system load quota of 1000 request per 2 seconds has been exceeded. send future request at slower rate or raise system quota.

I found somewhere that doing a IISREST fixes this, so I did a IISRESET / noforce and this did fix the issue but can anyone explain why this might happen so it does not happen in the future.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions given by error?  Reducing Kerberos auth requests, or raising the quota?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Steve Bryant's tool, EMTShooter ?

Here's a blog post describing the tool.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/12/07/3411644.aspx

You can download the tool here:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-Management-b9d918b1

The tool covers common EMC start-up issues related to WsMan / WinRM / Kerb Auth tickets etc.